# How can I join two Matrix in Java

Tags: java, join, matrix

I want to join 2 matrix with the same number of columns and different number of lines, but I'm wondering how can I do this with one command.

I already know how to do this using **for's**, then, I want to know if there is a command in Java that do the job for me.

For example

```
int m1[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

int m2[][] = {{10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}};
```

**Magic command to join them into a matrix m**

**int m = join(m1,m2);**

```
m = 

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

10 11 12

13 14 15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int m[][] = new int[m1.length+m2.length][];
System.arraycopy(m1, 0, m, 0, m1.length);
System.arraycopy(m2, 0, m, m1.length, m2.length);
```

You might want to clone each line though

Comment: Sorry dude, but it didn't worked. this method didin't accepted an matrix as parameters.

Comment: Sorry, it's arraycopy (with a lowercase c)

Answer (score 3):

Apache Commons is your friend:

```
int m[][] = (int [][])ArrayUtils.addAll(m1, m2);
```

Comment: I saw there is a lot of links to donwload in Apache Commons site. Wich one should I take for this?

Comment: apache commons-lang is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
int m[][] = Arrays.copyOf(m1, m1.length + m2.length);
System.arraycopy(m2, 0, m, m1.length, m2.length);
```

Comment: Sorry dude, but it didn't worked. this method didin't accepted an matrix as parameters.